# List in a cell the common values in N other cells with excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So if I have the following data

```
column1 column2 column3 
1,2,3   2,3,4   3,4,5
1       1,3,4   2
2       3,2     2,3
```

Is it possible with excel/spreadsheet to create a fourth column that will list all the common entries in column 1,2 and 3? Or possible to find values that are present in at least two (or N) columns? This is actually what I am looking for. Here is an expected output

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
1,2,3   2,3,4   3,4,5   2,3
1       1,3,4   2       1
2       3,2     2,3     2,3
```

I have seen multiple answers on how to do conditional highlighting to find duplicates in column but this is not really what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Some of your single values are followed by commas on the first column and the other columns are not. Which is the correct format? Can you please take a screen shot of some sample data and manually populate the 4th column with the expected output. Lastly, `Excel <> Google-Sheets` and are prone to different possible solutions. Which one are you using?

Comment: @urdearboy I have edited to provide expected output :). I'm basically interested in getting the values that appear in at least N column (in my test case N=2, but could be greater). I'd prefer google spreadsheets.

Comment: "...1,2 and 3?" Do you mean "or"? I don't see a `2` in `column3`...

Comment: @BruceWayne the rest before the expected output states: "Or possible to find values that are present in at least two (or N) columns? This is actually what I am looking for. Here is an expected output". So I am looking for a way to find values that are in at least N columns, with for now N=2

Comment: @LBes - D'oh! Sorry, didn't catch that. (I'll delete this comment shortly)

Comment: @BruceWayne you can leave it up, it's fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first row with data is row 1 (A1:C1) try

```
=join(", ", query(query(ArrayFormula(transpose(split(join(", ", A1:C1), ", "))&{"",""}), "Select Col1, Count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), "Select Col1 where Col2 > 1"))
```

or, if your locale requires the use of semicolons...

```
=join(", "; query(query(ArrayFormula(transpose(split(join(", "; A1:C1); ", "))&{""\""}); "Select Col1, Count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); "Select Col1 where Col2 > 1"))
```

and fill down as far as needed.

(Change range if needed).

EXPLANATION

- Create one row with all the values of A1:C1 in their own cell. To do that, join() all cells and then split use the comma as delimiter.
- Transpose to turn this row into a column.
- Create an identical column (with {"",""} )
- Use a first query to create a table of the values and their respective count.
- Use a second query to filter out the values with a count < 2.
- Use Join() to get the results in one cell (separated with a comma).

Comment: This seems complicated. Care to explain a bit? Also Spreadsheet returns an error when I tried just that

Comment: Don't know what your locale is, but try the second option in the updated answer.

Comment: that was indeed the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: If your column are not adjacents, is that easy to modify? I know where I have to change it, but I just don't how to write instead of "A1:C1" "A1 and C1 and E1"

Comment: {A1\C1\E1}. I also added a brief explanation.